# After creating an app wont show app page in any links or url

Tags: facebook

I have made many apps and have many client pages, but for some reason I just created a custom tab and there is no visit app page link on left side. Also I typed in the url for the app page and it said "facebook app not found", but it shows if I add static html: I Frame tabs

Answer (score 1):

Facebook announcing that **they will remove all App Profile Pages** on February 1st, 2012.

You will find **answere here**: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

Answer (score 0):

the profile page is normaly found via this url:

https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=your app id

Answer (score 0):

The new applications won't get a page automatically ... to add you application check de docs here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

It is possible to create a page per application, these will be similar to normal pages ( or fan pages )

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: thank you so much it did help i just didnt know how i missed this info earlier